# Looping over all dataframes in memory in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have 12 dataframes containing environmental data- each dataframe has a different month of data in it with 9934 rows and 38 columns.

To make my code as streamline as possible i want to create a for loop which loops over all dataframes in memory and carries out a task on them e.g. set the index of each dataframe.

I have tried creating a list of all dataframes in memory through:

```
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
```

However, when i then try:

```
for df in alldfs: 
    df.set_index(['LABEL'], inplace = True)
```

I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Does anyone know how i can loop over each of these 12 dataframes in memory, edit them (e.g. set index) and then save and move onto the next?

Comment: Your list has the names of the files and the not the files themselves. Store them as a dictionary instead where the keys are the filenames and values the files themselves.

Comment: I then need to go on to merge all the files with a seperate file (containing eastings and northings of each area) and calculate averages of a number of the columns. Can i still do this if the data are in dictionary format?

Comment: Sure, you can. If you're intending to merge them all any case, why not merge them upfront and then perform the data-frame wise operation?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the best practice would be to stock your dataframes in some kind of data structure (e. g. dictionary) but if you REALLY want to follow your current method, you need to use an `eval` on the elements of your list, because those are the names of your dataframe variables.

Something like that:

```
for df_name in alldfs: 
    eval(df_name).set_index(['LABEL'], inplace = True)
```